# How do you say “ring someone out” or “cash someone out” in French?

Tags: expressions, traduction

In the context of customer service how would you say something like “I can ring you out at this register!” or “I’ll cash you out down here”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a colloquial way you can say this ;

- Je vais vous prendre à la caisse X. *or*
- Je vous prend à la caisse X.

In a more courteous fashion you might say something like this ;

- Passez à la caisse X, s'il vous plait. *or*
- Mettez-vous à la caisse X, s'il vous plait.

There are numerous variants of these few forms, of course; instead of using a number for X, the approximate location of the cash-register might be used: "à cette caisse" (“I can ring you out at this register!”), "à cette caisse, là-bas", à la caisse du fond", "à la première caisse", etc.  Also, "s'il vous plait" can be fronted;

Instead of "passez", "Vous pouvez passer" will do as well but then "s'il vous plait" is no used unless the injunction takes the form of a question;

- Vous pouvez passer à cette caisse.
- Vous pouvez passer à cette caisse s'il vous plait ? (*more courteous*)

Other options used by cashiers

- Venez par ici madame/monsieur/mademoiselle, je vous encaisse. ("je vais vous encaisser", as well) (*the cashier is at the register where the customer is being asked to go.*)
- Par ici monsieur (s'il vous plait), je vous encaisse.  (*same remark as above*)
- Par ici, madame (s'il vous plait), c'est ouvert. (*same remark as above*)

Here again, the order of the expressions used is not fixed;

- Madame ! S'il vous plait, par ici, je vous encaisse. (*if it is needed to draw the attention of the person*)
- S'il vous plait , madame, par ici.
- S'il vous plait , madame, venez à ma caisse.

Comment: thank you so much! i’ll keep all of these in mind. i tried asking my french friend before and he said “scanner” but i get the impression he misunderstood a little? unless that’s another option?

Comment: @jacoballens I haven't  yet heard someone use that term, but it is a legitimate possibility as I see it; I have no idea of the line along which to use it; it seems "Je vais vous scanner à la caisse X." is not likely, but you never know, it might just be  one of the forms used; personally I'd say  something like "Je vais scanner vos articles."  or "Venez ici pour le scannage.", etc. and I think I wouldn't wait for some authority to make the form legitimate, as it says what is needed; it is already an alternative as "scanner des articles" is well understood (apparently).